# Passport.js Ajax login?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

Is it possible to login via ajax with passport.js?

The thing is i'm creating a user via ajax and i want it to be logged in automatically (everything with json in a restful style) but the req.login() does some stuff that i don't know and that apparently sends its own status, headers and even it redirects to the home but and i need is to create my own json response.

The code where i create the user:

signup_facebook: function (req, res) {

```
    var restponse = new Restponse();

    var body = req.body;

    var obj = {
        display_name: body.first_name,
        name: body.first_name,
        surname: body.last_name,
        photos: ['http://graph.facebook.com/'+ body.id+ '/picture?type=normal'],
        gender: body.gender,
        facebook: {
            userID: body.id,
            displayName: body.display_name
        }
    }

    User.facebookSignUp(obj, function(user){

        if(user !== false){
            user = obj;
            restponse.location = '/';
            restponse.status = HTTPStatus.REST.C201_OK;
        }else{
            restponse.location = '/';
            restponse.status = HTTPStatus.REST.C302_FOUND;
        }

        restponse.body = user;

        req.login(user, {}, function(err) {
            APIheart.respondJson(res, restponse);
        });
    })
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this post:

http://toon.io/on-passportjs-specific-use-cases/

```
// Manually establish the session...
req.login(user, function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.json({
        message: 'user authenticated',
    });
});
```

Comment: This still redirects for me